# Separate month and year columns, or date with day always set to 1?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, datetime

I'm building a database with Postgres where there's going to be a lot of grouping of things by `month` and `year`, but never by the `date`.

- I could create integer `month` and `year` columns and use those.
- Or I could have a `month_year` column and always set the `day` to 1.

The former seems a bit simpler and clearer if someone is looking at the data, but the latter is nice in that it uses a proper type.

Comment: Or you could create your own data type `month` that contains two integers. But I think if you never, ever need the day of the month, using two integers is probably easier

Comment: You should declare the possible range of dates, the possible number of rows, what you are trying to optimize (storage, performance, safety, simplicity?) and (as always) your version of Postgres.

Comment: Related: [How do you do date math that ignores the year?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15179731/939860)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Personally if it's a date, or can be a date, I suggest always storing it as one. It's just easier to work with as a rule of thumb.

- A date is 4 bytes.
- A smallint is 2 bytes (we need two)

  - ... 2 bytes: one smallint for year
  - ... 2 bytes: one smallint for month

You can have one date which will support day if you ever need it, or one `smallint` for year and month which will never support the extra precision.

## Sample data

Let's look at an example now.. Let's create 1 million dates for our sample. This is approximately 5,000 rows for 200 years between 1901, and 2100. Every year should have something for every month.

```
CREATE TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT
    x,
    make_date(year,month,1)::date AS date,
    year::smallint,
    month::smallint
  FROM generate_series(1,1e6) AS gs(x)
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL CAST(trunc(random()*12+1+x-x) AS int) AS month
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL CAST(trunc(random()*200+1901+x-x) AS int) AS year
;
CREATE INDEX ON foo(date);
CREATE INDEX ON foo (year,month);
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE foo;
```

## Testing

### Simple `WHERE`

Now we can test these theories of not using date.. I ran each of these a few times so as to warm things up.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM foo WHERE date = '2014-1-1'
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on foo  (cost=11.56..1265.16 rows=405 width=14) (actual time=0.164..0.751 rows=454 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (date = '2014-04-01'::date)
   Heap Blocks: exact=439
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on foo_date_idx  (cost=0.00..11.46 rows=405 width=0) (actual time=0.090..0.090 rows=454 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (date = '2014-04-01'::date)
 Planning time: 0.090 ms
 Execution time: 0.795 ms
```

Now, let's try the other method with them separate

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM foo WHERE year = 2014 AND month = 1;
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on foo  (cost=12.75..1312.06 rows=422 width=14) (actual time=0.139..0.707 rows=379 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((year = 2014) AND (month = 1))
   Heap Blocks: exact=362
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on foo_year_month_idx  (cost=0.00..12.64 rows=422 width=0) (actual time=0.079..0.079 rows=379 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((year = 2014) AND (month = 1))
 Planning time: 0.086 ms
 Execution time: 0.749 ms
(7 rows)
```

In fairness, they're not all 0.749.. some are a bit more or less, but it doesn't matter. They're all relatively the same. It simply isn't needed.

### Within one month

Now, let's have fun with it.. Let's say you want to find all intervals within 1 month of Jan 2014 (the same month we used above).

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  SELECT *
  FROM foo
  WHERE date
    BETWEEN
      ('2014-1-1'::date - '1 month'::interval)::date 
      AND ('2014-1-1'::date + '1 month'::interval)::date;
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on foo  (cost=21.27..2310.97 rows=863 width=14) (actual time=0.384..1.644 rows=1226 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((date >= '2013-12-01'::date) AND (date <= '2014-02-01'::date))
   Heap Blocks: exact=1083
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on foo_date_idx  (cost=0.00..21.06 rows=863 width=0) (actual time=0.208..0.208 rows=1226 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((date >= '2013-12-01'::date) AND (date <= '2014-02-01'::date))
 Planning time: 0.104 ms
 Execution time: 1.727 ms
(7 rows)
```

Compare that to the combined method

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  SELECT *
  FROM foo
  WHERE year = 2013 AND month = 12
    OR ( year = 2014 AND ( month = 1 OR month = 2) );

                                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on foo  (cost=38.79..2999.66 rows=1203 width=14) (actual time=0.664..2.291 rows=1226 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (((year = 2013) AND (month = 12)) OR (((year = 2014) AND (month = 1)) OR ((year = 2014) AND (month = 2))))
   Heap Blocks: exact=1083
   ->  BitmapOr  (cost=38.79..38.79 rows=1237 width=0) (actual time=0.479..0.479 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on foo_year_month_idx  (cost=0.00..12.64 rows=421 width=0) (actual time=0.112..0.112 rows=402 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((year = 2013) AND (month = 12))
         ->  BitmapOr  (cost=25.60..25.60 rows=816 width=0) (actual time=0.218..0.218 rows=0 loops=1)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on foo_year_month_idx  (cost=0.00..12.62 rows=420 width=0) (actual time=0.108..0.108 rows=423 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((year = 2014) AND (month = 1))
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on foo_year_month_idx  (cost=0.00..12.38 rows=395 width=0) (actual time=0.108..0.108 rows=401 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((year = 2014) AND (month = 2))
 Planning time: 0.256 ms
 Execution time: 2.421 ms
(13 rows)
```

It's both slower, and uglier.

### `GROUP BY`/`ORDER BY`

Combined method,

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  SELECT date, count(*)
  FROM foo
  GROUP BY date
  ORDER BY date;
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=20564.75..20570.75 rows=2400 width=4) (actual time=286.749..286.841 rows=2400 loops=1)
   Sort Key: date
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 209kB
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=20406.00..20430.00 rows=2400 width=4) (actual time=285.978..286.301 rows=2400 loops=1)
         Group Key: date
         ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..15406.00 rows=1000000 width=4) (actual time=0.012..70.582 rows=1000000 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.094 ms
 Execution time: 286.971 ms
(8 rows)
```

And again with the composite method

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  SELECT year, month, count(*)
  FROM foo
  GROUP BY year, month
  ORDER BY year, month;
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=23064.75..23070.75 rows=2400 width=4) (actual time=336.826..336.908 rows=2400 loops=1)
   Sort Key: year, month
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 209kB
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=22906.00..22930.00 rows=2400 width=4) (actual time=335.757..336.060 rows=2400 loops=1)
         Group Key: year, month
         ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..15406.00 rows=1000000 width=4) (actual time=0.010..70.468 rows=1000000 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.098 ms
 Execution time: 337.027 ms
(8 rows)
```

## Conclusion

Generally, let the smart people do the hard work. Datemath is hard, my clients don't pay me enough. I used to do these tests. I was hard pressed to ever conclude that I could get better results than `date`. I stopped trying.

## UPDATES

@a_horse_with_no_name suggested for my *within one month* test `WHERE (year, month) between (2013, 12) and (2014,2)`. In my opinion, while cool that's a more complex query and I'd rather avoid it unless there was a gain. Alas, it was still slower though it's close -- which is more of the take away from this test. It simply doesn't matter much.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  SELECT *
  FROM foo
  WHERE (year, month) between (2013, 12) and (2014,2);

                                                              QUERY PLAN                                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on foo  (cost=5287.16..15670.20 rows=248852 width=14) (actual time=0.753..2.157 rows=1226 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((ROW(year, month) >= ROW(2013, 12)) AND (ROW(year, month) <= ROW(2014, 2)))
   Heap Blocks: exact=1083
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on foo_year_month_idx  (cost=0.00..5224.95 rows=248852 width=0) (actual time=0.550..0.550 rows=1226 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((ROW(year, month) >= ROW(2013, 12)) AND (ROW(year, month) <= ROW(2014, 2)))
 Planning time: 0.099 ms
 Execution time: 2.249 ms
(7 rows)
```

Comment: Unlike some other RDBMS (See page 45 of http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-07/pagination-done-the-postgresql-way), Postgres also fully supports index access with row values: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34291099/939860 But that's an aside, I fully agree: `date` is the way to go in most cases.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to Evan Carroll proposed method, which I consider probably the best option, I've used in some occasions (and not specially when using PostgreSQL) just a `year_month` column, of type `INTEGER` (4 bytes), computed as

```
 year_month = year * 100 + month
```

That is, you encode the month on the two rightmost *decimal* digits (digit 0, and digit 1) of the integer number, and the year on the digits 2 through 5 (or more, if needed).

This is, to some extent, a *poor man's* alternative to building your own `year_month` type and operators. It's got some advantages, mostly "clarity of intent", and some space savings (not in PostgreSQL, I think), and also some inconveniences, over having two separate columns.

You can guarantee that values are valid by just adding a

```
CHECK ((year_date % 100) BETWEEN 1 AND 12)   /*  % = modulus operator */
```

You can have a `WHERE` clause looking like:

```
year_month BETWEEN 201610 and 201702
```

and it works efficiently (if the `year_month` column is properly indexed, of course).

You can group by `year_month` the same way you could do it with a date, and with the same efficiency (at least).

If you need to separate `year` and `month`, the computation is straightforward:

```
month = year_month % 100    -- % is modulus operator
year  = year_month / 100    -- / is integer division
```

What's **inconvenient**: if you want to add 15 months to a `year_month` you have to compute (if I've not made a mistake or oversight):

```
year_month + delta (months) = ...

    /* intermediate calculations */
    year = year_month/100 + delta/12    /* years we had + new years */
           + (year_month % 100 + delta%12) / 12  /* extra months make 1 more year? */
    month = ((year_month%10) + (delta%12) - 1) % 12 + 1

/* final result */
... = year * 100 + month
```

If you're not careful, this can be error prone.

If you want to get the number of months between two year_months, you need to do some similar computations. That's (with a lot of simplifications) what really happens under the hood with date arithmetic, that is luckily hidden from us through already defined functions and operators.

If you need lots of these operations, using `year_month` is not too practical. If you don't, it is a very clear way of making your intent clear.

---

As an alternative, you could define a `year_month` type, and define an operator `year_month` + `interval`, and also another `year_month` - `year_month` ... and hide the calculations. I've actually never made such a heavy use as to feel the need in practice. A `date`-`date` is actually hiding you something similar.

Comment: I wrote yet another way to do this =) enjoy it.

Comment: I appreciate the how-to as well as the pros and cons.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to joanolo's method =) (sorry I was busy but wanted to write this)

## BIT JOY

We're going to do the same thing, but with bits. One `int4` in PostgreSQL is a signed integer, ranging from -2147483648 to +2147483647

Here is an overview, of our structure.

```
               bit                
----------------------------------
 YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYMMMM
```

Storing month.

- A month requires 12 options `pow(2,4)` is **4 bits**.
- The rest we devote to the year, 32-4 = **28 bits**.

Here is our bit map of where months are stored.

```
               bit                
----------------------------------
 00000000000000000000000000001111
```

Months, 1-Jan - 12 Dec

```
               bit                
----------------------------------
 00000000000000000000000000000001
               bit                
----------------------------------
 00000000000000000000000000001100
```

Years. The remaining 28 bits allow us to store our year-information

```
SELECT (pow(2,28)-1)::int;
   int4    
-----------
 268435455
(1 row)
```

At this point we need to decide how we want to do this. For our purposes, we could use a static offset, if we only need to cover 5,000 AD, we could go back to `268,430,455 BC` which pretty much covers the entirety of [Mesozoic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesozoic) and everything useful moving forward.

```
SELECT (pow(2,28)-1)::int4::bit(32) << 4;
               year               
----------------------------------
 11111111111111111111111111110000
```

And, now we have the rudiments of our type, set to expire in 2,700 years.

So let's get to work on making some functions.

```
CREATE DOMAIN year_month AS int4;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_year_month (cstring text)
RETURNS year_month
AS $$
  SELECT (
    ( ((date[1]::int4 - 5000) * -1)::bit(32) << 4 )
    | date[2]::int4::bit(32)
  )::year_month
  FROM regexp_split_to_array(cstring,'-(?=\d{1,2}$)')
    AS t(date)
$$
LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION year_month_to_text (ym year_month)
RETURNS text
AS $$
  SELECT ((ym::bit(32) >>4)::int4 * -1 + 5000)::text ||
  '-' ||
  (ym::bit(32) <<28 >>28)::int4::text
$$ LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;
```

A quick test shows this working..

```
SELECT year_month_to_text( to_year_month('2014-12') );
SELECT year_month_to_text( to_year_month('-5000-10') );
SELECT year_month_to_text( to_year_month('-8000-10') );
SELECT year_month_to_text( to_year_month('-84398-10') );
```

Now we have functions that we can use on our binary types..

We could have cut off one more bit from the signed portion, stored the year as positive, and then had it sort naturally as a signed int. If speed was a higher priority than storage space, that would have been the route we go down. But for now, we have a date that works with the Mesozoic.

I may update later with that, just for fun.

Comment: Ranges aren't possible yet, I'll look at that later.

Comment: I think "optimizing to the bit" would make all the sense when you'd also make all the functions in "low level C". You save down-to-the-last bit and down-to-the-last nanosecond ;-) Anyhow, joyful! (I still remember BCD. Not necessarily with joy.)